# plot area truncated when using geom_dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

consider the following example data:

```
ex = structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
  2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
  2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
  1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
  5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), 
  ID = structure(c(35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
    22L, 22L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
    20L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
    33L, 34L), .Label = c("10", "107", "108", "109", "124", "17", 
      "18", "187", "19", "21", "24", "26", "27", "28", "335", "336", 
      "339", "340", "341", "342", "38", "39", "576", "577", "578", 
      "579", "580", "581", "582", "583", "584", "585", "586", "592", 
      "6"), class = "factor"), value = c(1L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 33L, 27L, 28L, 21L, 28L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -88L), .Names = c("group", "ID", "value")
)
```

Note that in group `A`, `value = 1` for every `ID`. I use `ggplot2` to create dot plot based on counts of the `value` variable using `geom_dotplot` and faceting by `group`:

```
ggplot(ex) + aes(x = value) + 
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1, method = "histodot") +
  facet_wrap(~ group)
```

The dot stack in the first facet is cut off, even when exported using `ggsave`. Changing the y-axis limits has no effect, but changing the aspect ratio so that H >= W seems to fix the issue (usually by adding way more space to the top than necessary). **Is this a bug, or am I specifying my dot plot incorrectly?**

**EDIT**

One workaround is to flip my dotplot and bin by the `y` variable:

```
ggplot(ex) + aes(x = group, y = value) + 
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1, method = "histodot", 
    binaxis = "y", stackdir = "centerwhole") +     
  facet_wrap(~ group, scales = "free_x")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two other parameters that can help you are `stackratio` and `dotsize`. For example:

```
ggplot(ex) + aes(x = value) + 
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1, method = "histodot", stackratio = 0.9, dotsize = .75) +
  facet_wrap(~ group)  +
  scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL)
```

You would need to tweak the numbers until you got the layout you wanted.

Comment: hmm interesting. This works, but I guess this indicates a bug? I would expect that `geom_dotplot` would be able to rescale the y-axis to capture every dot...

Comment: Actually, I guess not... that would mean `geom_dotplot` would have to rescale the dots. I see the issue now.

Comment: Yeah, I think it comes down to how much do you want the dotsize to be a fixed value that you can change, vs being scaled based on the y. Here the y axis doesn't really mean much, so most of the control is in the dot size.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting workaround using `geom_bar` that achieves the same structure as a dot plot but with rectangles:

```
ggplot(ex) + aes(x = value, group = ID) + 
  geom_bar(color = "black", fill = "white", width = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ group)
```

Although it results in rectangles (rather than dots) and you can't control the stack spacing. The rectangles get resized according to the plot window, which would be equivalent to tweaking the dot size in `geom_dotplot`. Also, it begs the question "why not just use a regular bar plot?"